# What is the largest positive integer $n$ for which there is a unique integer $k$ such that $\frac{8}{15}\lt \frac{n}{n+k}\lt \frac{7}{13}$?

Tags: inequality

> What is the largest positive integer $n$ for which there is a unique integer $k$ such that $\frac{8}{15}\lt \frac{n}{n+k} \lt \frac{7}{13}$?

I found this question in an question paper .I solved this inequality and discovered that if n is a multiple of 42 then it is true. But the question asked the largest value but I found infinitely many values. Please give me the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{8}{15}\lt \frac{n}{n+k} \lt \frac{7}{13}$$
is equivalent to
$$\frac{6}{7}n\lt k\lt \frac{7}{8}n\tag1$$

If $\frac{7}{8}n-\frac{6}{7}n\gt 2$, i.e. $n\gt 112$, then there are at least two $k$s satisfying $(1)$.

So, we have to have $n\le 112$.

$n=112$ is sufficient since $$(1)\iff 96\lt k\lt 98$$

So, the largest $n$ is $\color{red}{112}$.

Answer (score 1):

From $\frac{8}{15}\lt \frac{n}{n+k} \lt \frac{7}{13}$ one gets $\frac {6n}{7} \lt k \lt \frac {7n}{8}$ therefore, from unique condition, $\frac {7n}{8} - \frac {6n}{7} \le 2$ so $n \le 112$.